# which git command can tell me the exact commit that corrupted a given file?

Tags: git, debugging, logging

I have two git commits *c1* and *cn*. In my case cn is the tip of my current branch. *c1* is a great-great-ancestor of *cn*. Roughtly 20 commits are between them. My file test.py got corrupted somewhere on the way. Is there a way to figure out at which commit it got corrupted?

When I type

```
git diff c1 cn test.py
```

I do get all the differences between the two commits and indeed i see that it got changed to the worse. However, it doesnt tell me where it got changed! I would like to find the particular commit where i made the fatal change.

**Edit**: What I am really looking for is a verbose git diff. I can see what made the test.py buggy, but I want to know which commit was responsible for it. So a git diff with a verbose option would be great. One that adds the id and the message and the branch of the diffs.

Comment: Have you tried `git bisect`?

Comment: Consider also `git log -S` and `git log -G`. If the mistake is easily grep-able, these two commands will be the fastest way to find which commit had the error.

Comment: ... _and_ `git blame`

Comment: When you say corrupted, do you mean the test is broken, or the file itself was corrupted and cannot be read?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. @jonrsharpe: it worked! I narrowed it down with git bisect. Thanks. If you like you can write an answer and I would accept it. Also thanks to at torek and at eftshift and at Daly!  I havent tried those yet.

Comment: In that case it's a dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043816/find-commit-that-broke-a-test-without-running-every-test-on-every-commit

Comment: i guess its similar. But what i was really looking for is a verbose git diff

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-reading the question, but it certainly seems that `git log test.py` tells you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) for this. To find the issue:

1. `git checkout [cn]`
2. `git bisect start`
3. `git bisect bad`
4. `git bisect good [c1]`

Replace `[cn]` and `[c1]` with the respective commit SHA. This tells Git that `cn` is broken and `c1` is not broken. Git will do a binary search for the broken commit. It checks out the commit in the middle of `c1` and `cn` (roughly 10 commits away from each). Determine if this version is broken. If it is broken, run `git bisect bad`. If it is not broken, run `git bisect good`. Now Git will checkout another commit. Repeat until Git tells you the SHA and commit message of the broken commit.